# Convert object into an array Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I am new in javascript and angular. Suppose I have an JSON object with `{"xyz":{Key:info}}` . I want to add `{Key:info}` in to an array .

I want to make **"xyz"** an array. Eg: `{"xyz":[{Key:info}]}` So that I can push more of `{Key:info}` into that array- `{"xyz":[{Key:info},{Key:info},{Key:info}]}`.

Also I need to check every time if **xyz** is object then make it array and push only once.

I am not getting how can I do this with angular javascript.

**EDIT :-**  **Added orig JSON**

```
$scope.ContentObj= {
      "attribute-set": [
        {
          "attribute": [
            {
              "_name": "text-align",
              "__prefix": "xsl",
              "__text": "end"
            },
            {
              "_name": "end-indent",
              "__prefix": "xsl",
              "__text": "10pt"
            }
          ],
          "_name": "odd__header",
          "__prefix": "xsl"
        },
        {
          "attribute": {
            "_name": "font-weight",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "bold"
          },
          "_name": "pagenum",
          "__prefix": "xsl"
        }
      ],
      "_version": "2.0",
      "__prefix": "xsl"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `typeof` to know if it is an object and then you can get its content and initialize an array with it

```js
let myObject = {"xyz":{Key:"info"}};

if(typeof myObject.xyz === "object"){ //Check if object
  const content = myObject.xyz; //Get the content
  myObject.xyz = [content]; //Put the content in an array
}

console.log(myObject);
```

If you need to use it in your code as asked in the comments :

```
if(typeof $scope.ContentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].xyz === "object"){ //Check if object
  const content = $scope.ContentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].xyz; //Get the content
  $scope.ContentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].xyz = [content]; //Put the content in an array
}

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for the clean code. Now suppose I  need to call information in this way  `let myObject = $scope.ContentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].xyz;` , then in console I can see only object .

Comment: Then replace `myObject` by `$scope.ContentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4]` and leave the first line initializing the object

Comment: You mean to say the object `let myObject = {"xyz":{Key:"info"}};` should be hard coded ?

Comment: I am still confuse about the first line. `let myObject` . I have added my real JSON call in EDIT and I need to make it like first `attribute-set`. Call `scope.ContentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1]`. Here you can see `attribute-set[1].attribute` is object.

Comment: The first line is only to show you a demo. I am only creating a fake object similar to yours

Comment: Ok by hard coding the object I am able to to convert in array like yours successfully. -> `let myObject = {"attribute":{"_name":"font-weight","__prefix":"xsl","__text":"bold"},"_name":"pagenum","__prefix":"xsl"};
    
    if(typeof myObject.attribute === "object"){ //Check if object
      const content = myObject.attribute; //Get the content
      myObject.attribute = [content]; //Put the content in an array
    }` Now how will I replace `myObject` with `$scope.ContentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1]` ? everytime when the app is load ?

Comment: Just replace `typeof myObject === ..` by `typeof $scope.ContentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1] === ...` and do the same for the following line. You also have to delete the first line `let myObject = ...`. I see that you are missing the basics of javascript. You should first read tutorial about basic javascript

Comment: Thanks , I got it . Yes I got confused with so much mix  of code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem ! I am happy that it helped you

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are asking.

```
if (!angular.isArray($scope.yourObject.xyz)){
    $scope.yourObject = {
        xyz: []
    }
}
$scope.yourObject.xyz.push({Key:'info'})
```

Comment: I did that , but now somehow my array is getting pushed twice , Example `{"xyz":[[{Key:info},{Key:info},{Key:info}],{Key:info},{Key:info}]}`

Comment: But i think , this code will create array whenever the controller will get load each time.  I want to find object only once . And if array is there then skip.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
$scope.yourObject.xyz.push(Object.assign([], yourObject))
```